# UIView size after transform

Tags: ios, uiview

I need to get the size of `UIView` after applying transform such as `CGAffineTransformScale` and  `CGAffineTransformRotate` .I use the below method to get the size of the view but i am not able to get the accurate size after applying `CGaffineTransformRotate`.

```
  CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(view.bound.size,view.transform)
```

I am using this method because view.frame becomes NULL after applying transform.As mentioned in apple docs. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the accurate size vs what you're actually getting? What is the frame of the view before the rotation and can you be more specific about the transforms you are applying?

Answer (score 1):

The notion of "size" has no obvious meaning after application of a transform, and especially a rotation transform. That is why you are not supposed to access the `frame` of a view whose transform is not the identity transform.  `CGSizeApplyAffineTransform` certainly does give accurate information under one interpretation of the notion of size (and so does `frame`, which gives a nonrotated bounding box). You might want to think further, though, about why you believe you need this information.